# Continuous functions in L_p

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

The collection of all continuous complex functions on $X$ whose support is compact is denoted by $C_c(X)$.
In Rudin Book, Real and Complex Analysis, page 69.

Theorem 3.14  For $1\leq p< \infty$, $C_c(X)$ is dense in $L^p(\mu)$

My question is: why $C_c(X)$ is subset of $L^p(\mu)$?

That is to say, if $f\in C_c(X)$ then $\displaystyle \int_{X} |f| \, dx<\infty $

Help me. Thank you all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason that if $f\in C_c(X)$, $f$ has compact support, so that $\operatorname{supp}f\subseteq K$ for some compact set $K$. Since it is also continuous, we also have that $|f(x)|\le M$ for some $M$ and all $x$. (This follows from the extreme value theorem.) Thus,

$$\int_X |f(x)|^p\,dx = \int_K |f(x)|^p\,dx \le \int_K M^p\,dx = \mu(K)M^p.$$

Since $K$ is compact, $\mu(K)$ is finite, so $f\in L^p(\mu)$.

Comment: I had forgotten; Thank you Cameron Williams.

Comment: @Cameron: Good going on the 10K.

Comment: @gary Thanks :) Feels good to reach 10K.

Comment: @Cameron: Sure, :) .